# md-slider custom color slider - ANGULAR MATERIAL

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I am working on md-slider, Here my question is how can we have the color of the slider as own, as default the having two classes md-warn(for red), and md-primary(for white). I want white color slider.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visores'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35522357/2268426) answer was very useful, however this didn't quite match the functionality of the default slider insofar as the right hand side of the `md-thumb` ends up the same colour as the rest of the slider. By changing the
`.md-track` to `.md-track-fill`, you will match the default functionality. The code will therefore look as follows:

```
#red-slider .md-thumb:after, #red-slider .md-track-fill{
    background-color: greenyellow !important;
    border-color: greenyellow !important;
}
#red-slider .md-focus-thumb, #red-slider .md-focus-ring{
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOEPpr)

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve a custom color by overwriting the css-class of the slider.

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPJVbB)

```
#red-slider .md-thumb:after, #red-slider .md-track{
    background-color: greenyellow !important;
    border-color: greenyellow !important;
}
#red-slider .md-focus-thumb, #red-slider .md-focus-ring{
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

css classes to overwrite:

```
.md-thumb:after
.md-track
.md-focus-thumb 
.md-focus-ring
```

I didn´t tested all the functionality of the slider. But basically you have to overwrite all the styles from the slider. You can find them at the [git repo](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/slider/slider-theme.scss)

Answer (score 1):

Additional, you can custom the color of balloon on the md slider by this code:

```
#red-slider .md-sign, #red-slider .md-sign {
    background-color: blue;
    border-top-color: blue;
}

#red-slider .md-sign:after, #red-slider .md-sign {

    border-top-color: blue;
}
```

This can change the color of balloon as you neeeded